# Java multiple csv files to .data file?

Tags: java

I have never dealt with .data files before. I have 50 csv files which are 2-dimensional. I would like to split them into 2 separate .data files (as is required by a library I am using).

Is there any easy way to do this? How does a .data file look like?

Comment: why do you think there is only 1 kind of `.data` file? Which the library your are using?

Comment: What is a two-dimensional CSV file?

Comment: @Eypros I thought it was a standard file of some sort, I am dealing with Java-ML (Java - Machine Learning), specifically clustering via k-means.

Comment: @Duncan Two rows, separation of float values with commas.

Comment: Any particular reason to use Java-ML? Weka and Mahout seems to be better maintained.

Comment: @xgdgsc Been doing research and you are correct will be changing, any of the two you recommend as a beginner?

Comment: @KarlMorrison Weka is good enough on a single machine. Mahout is better if you need to scale up.